# Reactjs component `this.state` undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to reactjs and tried to make a component. I set `this.state` in `componentWillMount()` and after that I call a method:

```
componentWillMount() {
        this.setState({ value: this.props.value || "0" });
        this.changeCbState = this.changeCbState.bind(this); 
        this.changeCbState();
    }
```

But in my method `changeCBState` `this.state` is undefined:

```
changeCbState() {
        console.log(this.state.value)
    }
```

Error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null`

Comment: Have to defined this.state in constructor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem could be that you wouldn't have initialised state in the constructor and since this.setState is asynchronous the state may not be initialsed before you are trying to access in `changeCbState` function.

Also the initialisation code that you have written in `componentWillMount` lifecycle needs to go in `constructor` since the `componentWillMount` method is supposed to be deprecated.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
        this.state = {
           value: this.props.value || "0"
        }
        this.changeCbState = this.changeCbState.bind(this); 
        this.changeCbState();
    }
```

Comment: I changed my code as you said: `constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = ({ value: this.props.value || "0" });
        this.changeCbState = this.changeCbState.bind(this);
        this.changeCbState();
    }` but there is still the same error

Comment: You would need to correct the syntax `this.state = ({ value: this.props.value || "0" })` to `this.state = { value: this.props.value || "0" }`

Comment: This works! Thank you! But only if the constructor takes `props` as parameter. Why?

Comment: the props are sent to the class on instantiation. If you accept that argument you can use the props in your constructor

Comment: But I can use them e.g. in componentWillMount without passing them

Comment: yes thats because after the constructor runs, props are exposed to the class on a class member called `props`. methods like `componentWillMount` have the `this` context bound to them (in terms of the react context). And because they have `this` they have access to props via `this.props`

Answer (score 3):

You probably didn't define state in your constructor. use the constructor to bind methods on your class instance and to define state

```
class Something extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { value: props.value || '0' }
    this.changeCbState = this.changeCbState.bind(this);
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.changeCbState();
  }
  changeCbState() {
    console.log(this.state.value)
  }

}
```

Comment: can you post your whole class then? not going to be able to help without seeing the code

Comment: Works fine! Thank you. It was my fault

Comment: My fault was that my constructor didn't take `props`as parameter. Why is this necessary?

Comment: @DanielRose because `this.props` in the constructor is undefined. It hasn't been set on the class yet. Remember the constructor is the code that runs as the class is setting up. The class has the props passed to it when it is instantiated, so if you accept that argument in the constructor you can use the props in that way. does that make sense?

Comment: Yes that makes sense to me. And i can use them in other method like `componentWillMount` without passing them to the constructor or directly to the method because they are already set in the class?

Comment: @Shubham Khatri answered already but much thanks for your help! :)

Comment: @DanielRose yea i know lol, i was answering your comments on his answer :P

Answer (score 2):

This problem has so many different answers, but my **simple elegant favorite answer** is to use arrow functions when defining such function.

```
class Something extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { value: props.value || '0' }
  }

  changeCbState = () => {
    console.log(this.state.value)
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.changeCbState();
  }


}
```

---

If you want to know more about this problem which is `binding` in JS. read [this](http://reactkungfu.com/2015/07/why-and-how-to-bind-methods-in-your-react-component-classes/)

Comment: Thanks for this very helpful article!!

Answer (score 0):

`setState` works in an asynchronous way. That means after calling `setState` `this.state` variable is not immediately changed. So you should use callback to do something after `setState`.

And it is better to define `this.state` in constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the state in `componentWillMount` is considered an anti-pattern. Take a look at this resource https://vasanthk.gitbooks.io/react-bits/anti-patterns/04.setState-in-componentWillMount.html.

The reason why state is set to `null` is because you haven't defined a value previously and `setState` is an asynchronous operation.

You have to set the initial state as follows:

```
class Mycomponent extends Component {
  constructor(super) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: this.props.value || "0",
    };
  }
}
```